# Piecewise isomorphism versus equivalence in Grothendieck ring

Tags: ag.algebraic-geometry, grothendieck-rings, stratifications

$\DeclareMathOperator\Var{Var}$Let $K_{0}(\Var_{\mathbb{C}})$ be the Grothendieck ring of varieties over $\mathbb{C}$. The class of a variety, $X$, in $K_{0}$ is denoted $[\,X\,]$. If $X$ and $Y$ are varieties then we say that they are *piecewise isomorphic* if there are finite locally closed stratifications, $\{X_{i}\}$ of $X$, and $\{Y_{i}\}$ of $Y$, so that there exist isomorphisms $X_{i}\rightarrow Y_{i}$.

Note, if $X$ and $Y$ are piecewise isomorphic then we have $[\,X\,]=[\,Y\,]$ in $K_{0}(\Var_{\mathbb{C}})$. I expect the converse should be false, perhaps even generically so (in some sense).

**Question.** What is a simple example of a pair of varieties with equivalent classes in $K_{0}(\Var_{\mathbb{C}})$ which are not piecewise isomorphic?

Here is a candidate example; let $C$ be the affine cone inside $\mathbb{A}^{3}$ given by the equation $x^{2}+y^{2}+z^{2}=0$, and denote by $q\mathrel{:=}[\,\mathbb{A}^{1}\,]$ the Lefschetz motive. Then we have $[\,C\,]=q^{2}$, since removing the cone point we obtain a (Zariski locally trivial) $\mathbb{C}^{*}$ bundle over $\mathbb{P}^{1}$. I expect that $C$ is not piecewise isomorphic to $\mathbb{A}^{2}$. Another example is given by $\operatorname{SL}(2)$, which has class $q^{3}-q$, and which I presume is not piecewise isomorphic to $\mathbb{A}^{3}$ with a line removed.

**Edit.** As noted in the [comments](https://mathoverflow.net/questions/380473/constructible-isomorphism-versus-equivalence-in-grothendieck-ring#comment966401_380473) the example $C$ above is in fact piecewise isomorphic to the affine plane.

Comment: Isn't the $\mathbf C^\times$-bundle trivial over $\mathbf A^1$? Then you can break up both $C$ and $\mathbf A^2$ into a point, a $\mathbf C^\times$, and a $\mathbf C^\times \times \mathbf A^1$.

Comment: Good point, should have noticed that. Editing to reflect ur remark.

Comment: "constructibly isomorphic" sounds like a strengthening of isomorphic, rather than a weakening. Why not "piecewise isomorphic"?

Comment: @YCor, fair point. I'm by no means wedded to this terminology, u're welcome to edit if u like.

Comment: It's done. Is it right that $X,Y$ are Grothendieck-equivalent (i.e. $[X]=[Y]$) iff there exists $Z$ such that $X\sqcup Z$ and $Y\sqcup Z$ are piecewise isomorphic?

Comment: @YCor thanks. Re. your question I'm not sure but it seems that the answer should be no according to the K3 construction mentioned in an answer below.

Comment: @YCor if $X \amalg Z$ means a stratification whose pieces are $X$ and $Z$ (rather than a coproduct of schemes), then the answer to your question is yes. The relation $[X] - [Y]$ can be written as $\sum_i \big([V_i] - \sum_j [V_{ij}]\big) - \sum_i \big([W_i] - \sum_j [W_{ij}]\big)$ for some finite type $k$-schemes $V_i$, $W_i$ with stratifications $V_{ij}$, $W_{ij}$. This gives $$\sum_i \Big([V_i] - \sum_j [V_{ij}]\Big) - [X] = \sum_i \Big([W_i] - \sum_j [W_{ij}]\Big) - [Y]$$ in $\mathbf Z^{(\mathbf{Var}_k)}$ (*before* quotienting the scissors relations).

Comment: Without loss of generality, no $V_i$ appears as a $V_{ij}$ and no $W_i$ as a $W_{ij}$. Matching up the terms, possibly adding $[X] - [X]$ on the right hand side or $[Y] - [Y]$ on the left hand side, there is an isomorphism $\coprod_i V_i \cong \coprod_i W_i$ and exactly one of the $W_{ij}$ (resp. $V_{ij}$) is isomorphic to $X$ (resp. $Y$). The $W_{ij}$ and $V_{ij}$ give two stratifications of this space with matching pieces, except one piece is $X$ in the former and one piece is $Y$ in the latter.

Comment: By 'matching pieces' I mean up to isomorphism, not as subschemes of $\coprod_i V_i \cong \coprod_i W_i$. A good first example to keep in mind is $\mathbf P^2$ minus a line and $\mathbf P^2$ minus a circle: the most obvious space to take is $\mathbf P^2$ (but in this case you can also find a piecewise isomorphism). With the K3 example, what has to happen is that $X \amalg Z$ and $Y \amalg Z$ have $Z$ as the big open piece, for otherwise the same birationality argument would apply. I find it kind of hard to picture...

Comment: A refinement that is conceptually much more satisfying and that solves a lot of these issues is the graded Grothendieck ring of [this paper](https://arxiv.org/abs/2004.08161) of Nicaise and Ottem. Basically, when looking at $n$-dimensional varieties, you do not want to allow scissors relations that involve higher-dimensional stuff. (The usefulness to birational questions of keeping track of the dimension was already clear from [this paper](https://arxiv.org/abs/1202.2676) of Kotschick and Schreieder, and Nicaise–Ottem lift Theorem 2 of Kotschick–Schreieder to the Grothendieck ring.)

Answer (score 4, accepted):

There are no simple examples as yet; it's been an open question going back to at least [Larsen and Lunts - Motivic measures and stable birational geometry](https://arxiv.org/abs/math/0110255), which has been open for about 15 years, and some of us believed that it should be true.

The first counterexample for smooth non-projective varieties was constructed by Borisov as a consequence on his work on L-zero divisors: [Borisov - The class of the affine line is a zero divisor in the Grothendieck ring](https://arxiv.org/abs/1412.6194).

There are currently no counterexamples known for smooth projective varieties. Specifically it is not known if $X$, $Y$ are smooth connected projective varieties over a field of characteristic zero such that $[X] = [Y]$, whether $X$ and $Y$ must be birational; they are stably birational by the work of Larsen and Lunts above.

Answer (score 4):

After a little digging in the literature, I found the following example:

**Theorem.** [KS18, Thm. 1.9] *There exist non-isomorphic K3 surfaces $X$ and $Y$ over $\mathbf C$ such that*
$$[X \times \mathbf A^1] = [Y \times \mathbf A^1].$$

Now if $X \times \mathbf A^1$ and $Y \times \mathbf A^1$ were constructibly isomorphic, then in particular they would be birational. But stably birational surfaces are birational (in this case I believe this follows simply by considering minimal models), which in the case of K3 surfaces would imply $X \cong Y$.

---

**References.**

[KS18]  A. Kuznetsov and E. Shinder, [*Grothendieck ring of varieties, D- and L-equivalence, and families of quadrics*](http://dx.doi.org/10.1007/s00029-017-0344-4). Selecta Math. (N.S.) 24.**4** (2018), p. 3475–3500. [ZBL06941785](https://zbmath.org/?q=an:06941785).

Comment: Thank u very much, I accepted the answer above (by one of the authors of the paper u cite!) bc it was two minutes prior to this one, which I would have been happy to accept as well.

Comment: @EBz totally agreed. I also think the other answer is better in terms of proper attribution.